# problem data I2C to sensor GY955/BNO055 (China)

Tags: arduino-mega, arduino-ide, i2c, serial-data, bno055

I want to ask, I have a problem when running the Arduino sensor, I can't output data, but it's detecting that the sensor address has been paired.
Like I2C has a problem or locks it.

Last night it worked only because my twin sensors tried another with the same program after I compiled and uploaded, I see the serial monitor is only a detection sensor, but it doesn't display data, so the pitch evaporates and the roll data is 0.0,0.

There seems to be a problem with i2c: the data does not come out, it only detects the sensor address but the contents are all zero. Have you ever experienced this?

This initially worked, because the sensor was the same and I tried it with the same program after reading GY 955 / BNO055 on Euler_streaming it only showed zero per axis.

This is code in the bread board

```
/****************************************************************************

    Euler_Streaming.pde - part of sample SW for using BNO055 with Arduino

   (C) All rights reserved by ROBERT BOSCH GMBH

   Copyright (C) 2014 Bosch Sensortec GmbH

    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
   (at your option) any later version.

    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

 **************************************************************************/
/*  Date: 2014/01/07
     Revision: 1.2

*/
#include "BNO055_support.h"     //Contains the bridge code between the API and Arduino
#include <Wire.h>

//The device address is set to BNO055_I2C_ADDR2 in this example. You can change this in the BNO055.h file in the code segment shown below.
// /* bno055 I2C Address */
// #define BNO055_I2C_ADDR1                0x28
// #define BNO055_I2C_ADDR2                0x29
// #define BNO055_I2C_ADDR                 BNO055_I2C_ADDR2

//Pin assignments as tested on the Arduino Due.
//Vdd,Vddio : 3.3V
//GND : GND
//SDA/SCL : SDA/SCL
//PSO/PS1 : GND/GND (I2C mode)

//This structure contains the details of the BNO055 device that is connected. (Updated after initialization)
struct bno055_t myBNO;
struct bno055_euler myEulerData; //Structure to hold the Euler data

unsigned long lastTime = 0;

void setup() //This code is executed once
{
  //Initialize I2C communication
  Wire.begin();

  //Initialization of the BNO055
  BNO_Init(&myBNO); //Assigning the structure to hold information about the device

  //Configuration to NDoF mode
  bno055_set_operation_mode(OPERATION_MODE_NDOF);

  delay(1);

  //Initialize the Serial Port to view information on the Serial Monitor
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() //This code is looped forever
{
  if ((millis() - lastTime) >= 100) //To stream at 10Hz without using additional timers
  {
    lastTime = millis();

    bno055_read_euler_hrp(&myEulerData);            //Update Euler data into the structure

    Serial.print("Time Stamp: ");               //To read out the Time Stamp
    Serial.println(lastTime);

    Serial.print("Heading(Yaw): ");             //To read out the Heading (Yaw)
    Serial.println(float(myEulerData.h) / 16.00);       //Convert to degrees

    Serial.print("Roll: ");                 //To read out the Roll
    Serial.println(float(myEulerData.r) / 16.00);       //Convert to degrees

    Serial.print("Pitch: ");                //To read out the Pitch
    Serial.println(float(myEulerData.p) / 16.00);       //Convert to degrees

    Serial.println();                   //Extra line to differentiate between packets
  }
}
```

Comment: Can someone find a schematic of the gy955?

Comment: How do you know, that the sensor was found at the address? What library are you using (link)? Is the address defined in the `BNO055_support.h`?

Comment: Hari_Murti, did you connect the vcc of the module to the 3.3v pin or the 5v pin of the arduino mega 2560?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the Adafruit library. When a Chinese module is used the **id needs to be specified** in the constructor like this:

```
Adafruit_BNO055 bno = Adafruit_BNO055(55,0x29);
```